# in extjs error in fill combo with ajax request

Tags: asp.net, ajax, extjs

working code:

```
var CustomStore = new Ext.data.Store({

    model: 'User',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'http://Test/Service1.svc/GetOperator',
        pageParam: false, 
        startParam: false, 
        limitParam: false, 
        noCache: false, 

        params: {
            storeID: 31
        },
        autoSync: true,
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'users'
        }

    },

    autoLoad: true
});
```

---

```
Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name: 'StaffID', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'Name', type: 'string' }
    ]
});
```

---

declare bind

```
               }, {
               id: 'cmbAppOperator',
               itemId: 'OperatorId',
               name: Ext.calendar.data.EventMappings.OperatorId.name,
               fieldLabel: 'Operator',
               xtype: 'combo',
               anchor: '60%',
               store: CustomStore,
               valueField: 'StaffID',
               displayField: 'Name',
               queryMode: 'local',
               allowBlank: false
           },
```

this is working code for below json

but error with same just change in URL for request

the json responce below:

```
[
 {
  "Name": "-Any Operator-",
 "StaffID": 0
 },
 {
 "Name": "aa Manzie",
 "StaffID": 37
 },
{
"Name": "tttt Sadsad",
"StaffID": 33
}
]
```

> "{\"OperatorListForAppointment\":[{\"Name\":\" Any operator \",\"OperatorID\":0},{\"Name\":\"aa Manzie\",\"OperatorID\":37}]}"

below are the code

var CustomStore = new Ext.data.Store({

```
    model: 'User',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        limitParam: 'false',
        noCache: false,
        pageParam: 'false',
        startParam: 'false',            

        url: 'https://test/POS/SalesService.svc/GetOperatorListForAppointments',
        params: {
            storeID: 31,
            shiftDate: '2016-07-05 04:29:36.840',
            dataBaseName: 'DB_Test'
        },
        autoSync: true,
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'users'
        }

    },

    autoLoad: true
});
```

---

```
     Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name: 'OperatorID', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'Name', type: 'string' }
    ]
});
```

---

```
              }, {
               id: 'cmbAppOperator',
               itemId: 'OperatorId',
               name: Ext.calendar.data.EventMappings.OperatorId.name,
               fieldLabel: 'Operator',
               xtype: 'combo',
               anchor: '60%',
               store: CustomStore,
               valueField: 'OperatorID',
               displayField: 'Name',
               queryMode: 'local',
               allowBlank: false
           },
```

i am confused please let me know where i am wrong.

Comment: R u getting data from backend on changed url ?

Answer (score 0):

The root property has to be defined as OperatorListForAppointment in store proxy instead of users as your response JSON contains array attribute as OperatorListForAppointment.